# Creating Wordpress like shortcode in laravel blade

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-4, shortcode

I have a mail template (in laravel blade) that is need to be dynamic (so it should be saved in database i think). This is the registration_complete.blade.php:

```
      <html>
       <body>
         {{$dynamic_content_from_database}}
        </body>
      </html>
```

And the $dynamic_content_from_database value came from the WYSIWYG i used.This is the management i worked for :
[image]

I need to find a way that admin user can manage the content of the template with variable inside or shortcode. Just like in WordPress they used short code to put the dynamic value in the content. I tried echoing the $dynamic_content_from_database. But it was just echoing the `[username]` as string. I tried to search trough web but i get no luck. By the way, i used laravel 4.2.This form is sent after successful registration.

Comment: Have you seen [this library for Laravel-Shortcodes](https://github.com/patrickbrouwers/Laravel-Shortcodes)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the better way to do is to prepare $dynamic_content_from_database BEFORE you put it in blade-template in your controller.

in route

```
Route::post('register', ['as'=>'register.post', 'uses'=> 'path\to\register\form\namespace@register']
```

in controller (easy, but not the best way):

```
public function replacement($string, array $placeholders)
{
    $resultString = $string;
    foreach($placeholders as $key => $value) {
        $resultString = str_replace('[' . $key . ']' , trim($value), $resultString, $i);
    }
    return $resultString;
}

public function register() {
    $data = Input::all();
    //... Dont forget about validation
    //loading template from database example
    $template = Template::where('name', 'register.success')->firstOrFail();
    $content = $this->replacement($template['text'], $data);
    View::make('register.success', ['content' => $content]); //or send mail with $content as you want
}
```

For better solution you might want to create TemplateService, enable it in config and load through App.

Comment: You saved my time! It worked great but i am interested to do it in a best way later on. I don't know about the TemplateService., but i will try to find out.Could you give us an example? At least i have a quick solution to this. Thank you again.

Comment: When I said about TemplateService I ment just ServiceProvider logic, read about service providers [there](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc#service-providers)
        You have to include template functions in solo-class, which does only one things: template-things
        After that you can use this service in any place of your application through $template = App::make('YourService') and templater will be single for use and for changes logic of templater