# How to add Google Ads between paragraph in post by Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, ads

I want to know how i use Google Ads in my project between paragraphs, Should they be entered manually? Or is there a String or function that add it automatically between paragraphs ??

I'm using Laravel 5.3, Thank you

Comment: can u show us some code? this question is too vague

Comment: @flex_ i have not code to show it, i asked about  if i get post from db and show it in <p>, how i add Ads between paragraphs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There so many way. But the most simple one is to  create something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691476/creating-wordpress-like-shortcode-in-laravel-blade) . Adding the ads to your content by SHORT CODE. You can put it anywhere you want on your content.

or

Adding the advertisement automatically after a certain number of characters. All you have to do is to prepare the content before displaying it.